# A Tough Mechanics Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation

Here's the problem diagram:

[image: 1]

The situation is set up on a fixed frictionless horizontal table. We are required to find the time after which the block B crosses the dotted line. The diameter of the pulley is negligible in comparision to $\ell$ (half length of string).The pulley and the strings are ideal and the dimensions of the blocks are irrelevant.

Here's my attempt: I consider the pulley, string and the blocks together as a system. Now there are external forces on my system(due to the pulley support), so I cannot apply Momentum conservation in the problem. The only forces on block A is Tension, so I tried solving the problem in frame of B by applying suitable pseudo-force on B and considering the motion of B as a horizontal circle with varying radius, but Im at loss as to what to do after this.

How can I proceed further using this method? Or if Im thinking incorrectly, is there a better/correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: If it is on a horizontal table then there is no gravity and nothing accelerating the block. So the problem is rather simple as it consists of constant rotational motion, with the radius of rotation $\ell$.

Comment: shouldnt the radius of rotation change continuously as block A moves?

Comment: Correct, I didn't see that itially.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think this is not an easy problem. In the limit of $m$ going to infinity, your answer should approach the time it takes a pendulum swinging 90 degrees which involves an Euler beta function.

Comment: well I did mention it was tough, I wrote the motion equations for the blocks, but the differential equations so generated are unsolvable for me, they are second order and they dont teach that in my high school.

Comment: Have you tried Conservation of Energy (the system is frictionless)?

Comment: while applying energy conservation, I have gotten 2 equations but I Have 3 variables to solve for, and I cannot apply momentum conservation to get the third equation.

Comment: and i dont think energy conservation would provide me with any time interval

Comment: You have conservation of angular momentum for B with respect to the pulley. You also have conservation of energy. These two will give an equation for the rate of change of the distance between B and the pulley $\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$ and the distance $r(t)$. Then you can integrate this equation to find the time.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll just outline a method of obtaining the equations of motion.

I don’t know if you’re familiar with Lagrangian mechanics. If you are, use polar coordinates for position of $B$ which specifies the system (constant length of string fixes position of $A$). From this you’ll obtain simply the kinetic energies of $A,B$ and potential energy of $B$, which gives the Lagrangian. Using Euler-Lagrange, you get the equations of motion.

For your attempt, I think it may not be the simplest path, the frame of $B$ even if yoh keep it parallel to the reference (which you didn’t precise btw), has a complicated acceleration which is what you want to solve in the first place.

If you want a more Newtonian approach, keep the same spirit of the above approach. Lets write $r,\phi$ the polar coordinates of $B$ (origin of $\phi$ is the downward direction, the angle thus varies from $\pi/4$ to $0$), and $x$ the position of $A$ (origin at the pulley, oriented to left), and $T$ the tension of the string. First off, in-extensibility gives, $x+r=2l$
and 2d law on $A$ gives
$$
T=-m\ddot x
$$
and applied on $B$ gives
$$
m(\ddot r - r\dot \phi ^2)=-T+mg\cos \phi
$$

and substituting the value of $T$ and $x$, you get:
$$
m(\ddot r - r\dot \phi ^2)=-m\ddot r +mg\cos \phi
$$
$$
m(2\dot r \dot \phi +r\ddot \phi)=mg\sin \phi
$$

(As usual, mass falls out, only the relative mass matters) You can further simplify the equations of motion, using conservation laws like energy:
$$
0 = m\dot r^2 -mg\cos\phi
$$
You’ll need an additional conserved quantity to integrate it analytically, or you you can solve this numerically.

Hope this helps, and tell me if something’s not clear.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the detailed solution, its much appreciated. Yeah, Im not famililiar with Lagrangian Mechanics but I might give it a try this summer vacation if its this useful. The terms of gravity are not required in the equations btw as I did mention the situation is set up on a horizontal frictionless plane, however I get the general idea on how to proceed in the latter case. Can the another conservation equation be the angular momentum conservation equation about the pulley?

Comment: Oops. My bad, yes without gravity you also have conservation of angular momentum and the system is fully integrable (and considerably simplifies the problem). Just realized that @Hosein mentioned it already. Just set $g=0$ in my previous equations, but for the resolution use the two conserved quantities: $E=v_0^2/2=\dot r^2/2$ and $L=lv_0=r^2\dot\phi$. Solve first for $r$ then $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

To get started with problems like this, recognize the DOFs of the system. I see 2 DOFs, one being $x$ how much block **A** has slid, and the second one $\theta$ the swing angle of block **B**.

The describe the center of mass of each body in terms of these variables

$$\begin{aligned} 
  x_A & = -\ell+ x & x_B & = (\ell+x) \cos \theta \\
  y_A & = 0 & y_B & = -(\ell+x) \sin \theta \\
\end{aligned}$$

I have placed a coordinate system on the pulley, with *x* pointing to the right, and *y* pointing upwards on the screen.

Now we need some calculus to describe the acceleration of each block in terms of the DOF variables and their derivatives.

First the velocity kinematics

$$\begin{aligned}\dot{x}_{A} & =\dot{x} & \dot{x}_{B} & =\dot{x}\cos\theta-(\ell+x)\dot{\theta}\sin\theta\\
\dot{y}_{A} & =0 & \dot{y}_{B} & =-\dot{x}\sin\theta-(\ell+x)\dot{\theta}\cos\theta
\end{aligned}$$

and the acceleration kinematics

$$\begin{aligned}\ddot{x}_{A} & =\ddot{x} & \ddot{x}_{B} & =-(\ell+x)\dot{\theta}^{2}\cos\theta+\ddot{x}\cos\theta-(\ell+x)\ddot{\theta}\sin\theta-2\dot{x}\dot{\theta}\sin\theta\\
\ddot{y}_{A} & =0 & \ddot{y}_{B} & =(\ell+x)\dot{\theta}^{2}\sin\theta-\ddot{x}\sin\theta-(\ell+x)\ddot{\theta}\cos\theta-2\dot{x}\dot{\theta}\cos\theta
\end{aligned}$$

Next step is to apply Newton's second law by describing all the forces acting on each body. Block **A** has the tension $T$ acting horizontally and we can ignore the vertical balance, and block **B** the tension $T$ acting on an angle $\theta$

$$\begin{aligned}T & =m\,\ddot{x}_{A} & -T\cos\theta & =m\,\ddot{x}_{B}\\
 & \text{(ignore)} & T\sin\theta & =m\,\ddot{y}_{B}
\end{aligned}$$

These three equations are to be solved for $T$, $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{\theta}$.

$$ \begin{aligned}
 T & = \frac{x+\ell}{2} m \dot{\theta}^2 \\
 \ddot{x} & = \frac{x+\ell}{2} \dot{\theta}^2 \\
 \ddot{\theta} & = - \frac{2 \dot{x} \dot{\theta}}{x+\ell}
\end{aligned} $$

By separation of variables, the last equation can be integrated into

$$ \int \frac{1}{\dot{\theta}}\,{\rm d}\dot{\theta} =  -\int \frac{2}{x+\ell}\,{\rm d}x + C$$

and from the inital condition $\dot{\theta}|_{x=0} = \frac{v_0}{\ell}$ the value of $C$ is found.

$$ \dot{\theta} = \frac{\ell v_0}{(x+\ell)^2} $$

Now use the above solution in the equation for $\ddot{x}$ to get

$$ \ddot{x} = \frac{\ell^2 v_0^2}{2 ( x+\ell)^3} $$

and directly integrate using (and a different $C$)

$$ \frac{1}{2} \dot{x} = \int \frac{\ell^2 v_0^2}{2 ( x+\ell)^3} \,{\rm d}x + C$$

and with the initial condition that $\dot{x}|_{x=0} = 0$ the expression for $\dot{x}$ in terms of $x$ is found

$$ \tfrac{1}{2} \dot{x}^2 - \frac{v_0^2}{4} = -\frac{\ell^2 v_0^2}{4 (\ell+x)^2} $$

Another integration gives as time

$$ t = \int \frac{1}{\dot{x}}\,{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{v_0} \sqrt{ 2 x (x+2\ell) }$$

Now we combine the expression for $\dot{\theta}$ in terms of $x$ with the above, and integrate over time to get

$$ \theta = \sqrt{2} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{v_0 t}{\sqrt{2} \ell} \right) $$

The problem is asking for $t$ when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thank You for providing a detailed solution! I did try the question using the motion equations as you did, but the monstrosity of the differential equations so formed scared me so I didnt proceed further. Looks like I need to brush up some calculus.

Comment: Also, I dont think you correctly integrated the first differential equation, but I get the general Idea, thank you.

Comment: @RajShukla - it helps to use a CAS for the calculus. It is entirely possible I have made some mistakes, but it is really the process that matters here.